# Find $\lim_{n \to +\infty }{\frac{n(1-nx_n)}{\ln{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence:
\begin{equation}
(x_n):
\begin{cases}
x_0\in(0, 1),\\ 
x_{n+1}=x_n - x_n^2,&n\geq 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Find
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to +\infty }{\frac{n(1-nx_n)}{\ln{n}}}\tag{*}
\end{equation}

My progress:

This is the second part of a problem, the first part is proving $\lim_{n \to +\infty }nx_n=1$ (**), which I already did.

And I'm not that naive to substitute (**) directly into (*), as it will return $0$, which is ridiculously simple.

And through trial and error, I found out the limit is $1$, but don't know how to prove it.